# How to render conditional actions in EmberJs?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I render actions based on a condition?

```
<a href="#" {{if item.active action 'myAction'}}>{{item.label}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it out, but I guess this could work:

```
<a href="#" {{action (if item.active 'ifAction' 'elseAction')}}>{{item.label}}</a>
```

If this doesn't work, maybe you will have to wrap the entire element into an if-else clause:

```
{{#if item.active}}
 <a href="#" {{action 'ifAction'}}>{{item.label}}</a>
{{else}}
 <a href="#" {{action 'elseAction'}}>{{item.label}}</a>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should move to closure actions. Then remember, the if/else can return anything, even functions and so actions:

```
<a onclick={{if active (action 'ifaction') (action 'elseaction')}}>click</a>
```